# How can I return a mutable reference to a value owned by the current function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, mutable-reference

Here is my struct and I need a `get_mut` function that returns a mutable reference to a value owned either by
`ctx.scope` or `ctx.parent.scope` recursively

```rust
pub type RuntimeContext<'c> = Rc<RefCell<Context<'c>>>;

pub struct Context<'c> {
    pub parent: Option<RuntimeContext<'c>>,
    pub scope: HashMap<String, Value>,
    pub eval: Value,
}
```

This is what I tried, but as expected the borrow checker complains:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> src/lib.rs:20:13
   |
20 |             parent.borrow_mut().get_mut(key) // here it breaks
   |             -------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             returns a reference to data owned by the current function
   |             temporary value created here
```

What other way is there to achieve this?

(the parent ctx is guaranteed to outline the current ctx)

```rust
impl<'c> Context<'c> {
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, key: &str) -> Option<&mut Value> {
        if let Some(v) = self.scope.get_mut(key) {
            Some(v)
        } else if let Some(parent) = &mut self.parent {
            parent.borrow_mut().get_mut(key) // here it breaks
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    // ... some other methods
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `'c` in the `Context` struct? It only references itself ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; there simply is no way to return a `&mut` reference to member of an object wrapped in `Rc<RefCel<>>`. `RefCell` requires a guard object to keep track whether the object is currently borrowed. A `&mut` reference, however, does no such thing, making it impossible to know for the `RefCell` that the `&mut` reference exists after its guard got dropped. Which happens at the end of the function.

It would, in general, be possible to return something that still contains the guard object, but that would of course not be compatible with the other return path where you want to return a reference from the `scope` member.

There are two ways I could think of how to achieve this:

- An enum return value that could return either a reference or a guard object
- A context manager like closure based approach where you return nothing, but instead call a given function with your value

The enum return value is quite difficult to get right and will become very complicated due to the multiple-layers-deep nesting of variables.

*EDIT:* I don't think the enum idea would work because it would run into lifetime problems.

So I personally would go with the second option.

Here is how that could look like:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Value;

pub type RuntimeContext<'c> = Rc<RefCell<Context<'c>>>;

pub struct Context<'c> {
    pub parent: Option<RuntimeContext<'c>>,
    pub scope: HashMap<String, Value>,
    pub eval: Value,
}

impl<'c> Context<'c> {
    pub fn get_mut<R>(&mut self, key: &str, f: impl FnOnce(Option<&Value>) -> R) -> R {
        if let Some(v) = self.scope.get_mut(key) {
            f(Some(v))
        } else if let Some(parent) = &mut self.parent {
            parent.borrow_mut().get_mut(key, f) // here it breaks
        } else {
            f(None)
        }
    }

    // ... some other methods
}

// Example on how to use this
pub fn do_something(context: &mut Context) {
    let y = context.get_mut("foobarkey", |value| {
        println!("Got value: {:?}", value);
        let computed_result = 42;
        computed_result
    });

    println!("Result: {}", y);
}
```

Comment: There's a third possibility, somewhat unsavoury, of boxing the reference or guard and returning a `Box<dyn Deref<Target=Value>>`.

Comment: @eggyal I am unsure in this situation how to put the return value of `Option<Rc<RefCell<Context>>>`,  in a `Box<dyn Deref<Target=Value>>`. I don't think it's properly possible due to lifetime problems.

Comment: I had been thinking of something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a53f4855fab44bd07185603eb841f2a) but you're right of course, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't thin the enum variant works either since you'd have to keep a stack of `RefMut`s all referencing the previous one.

Comment: @cafce25 Yah, I kind of had a feeling it would be like that.

Comment: @cafce25 Added a comment in my answer.